# Is there a way to join row values from 3 to 3?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

As I mentioned in the title, I need to get values from the first 3 rows, then the second 3 rows, and on, and join them in rows.

**Example**

Input:

```
column  
-------
Mu1
Mu2
Mu3
Mu4
Mu5
Mu6
Mu7
Mu8
Mu9
```

Output:

```
Column
------------
Mu1,Mu2,Mu3
Mu4,Mu5,Mu6 
Mu7,Mu8,Mu9
```

Thank you so much, and I'm sorry if I'm posting something in the wrong way, this is my first question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function (`row_number`) inside a CTE to assign a row number to each of your row.

Then you can use a `group by` with `string_agg` to concatenate your values 3 rows at a time:

```
declare @t table (col varchar(5))
insert into @t
values
('Mu1'),
('Mu2'),
('Mu3'),
('Mu4'),
('Mu5'),
('Mu6'),
('Mu7'),
('Mu8'),
('Mu9')

;with grp as 
(
   select col,
     rn = row_number() over (order by col)
   from @t
)
select 
    string_agg(col, ',') as [Column]
from grp
group by (rn -1)/ 3
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: I'm very grateful Andrea!! this works perfectly, it was an assignment for my work and it was driving me crazy for days. You are a genius!!!.